# Sorting on Date field in lightning data table is only sorting with Day not with Day month and year(complete Date value) in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, sort

Hi I have a lightning data table in which sorting on Date field is only sorting with 'Day' not with Day month and year(complete Date value) in LWC.

Lightning Data Table :

[image]

Code I am using for sorting :

[image]

Can anybody please help on getting it sorted with full date value

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! (a) please don't use screenshots to display code. The `{}` button in the editor will format your code in a code block nicely. (b) What format are your dates in?

Comment: The format of Dates is DD MMM YYYY. For example : 22 Jul 2020. I tried by updating the format to DD/MM/YYYY (22/07/2020) too, but the behaviour is same in that case too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing dates, you should format them in ISO-8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD). This would allow proper sorting. Here's a modification you could do:

```
sortData(fieldName, sortDirection) {
  let sortResult = [...this.data]; // Same as Object.assign([], this.data)
  let parser = (v) => v;
  let column = this.columns.find(c=>c.fieldName===fieldName);
  if(column.type==='date' || column.type==='datetime') {
    parser = (v) => (v && new Date(v));
  }
  let sortMult = sortDirection === 'asc'? 1: -1;
  this.data = sortResult.sort((a,b) => {
    let a1 = parser(a[fieldName]), b1 = parser(b[fieldName]);
    let r1 = a1 < b1, r2 = a1 === b1;
    return r2? 0: r1? -sortMult: sortMult;
  });
}
```

This extra parsing step converts dates (particularly dates that were in locale format) to a proper date, allowing proper sorting.

Comment: Thanks! It's working.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue today. What helped me was using the fieldName param we get from the column click event, looking through the table column header array, and getting the field type.

```
var fieldType;
 for(var i = 0; i < tableColumns.length; i++){              
     if(tableColumns[i].fieldName == fieldtoSort){
         fieldType = tableColumns[i].type;
         break;
     }
 }
```

From there if it's a "date" we can convert it to something that's sortable and use the regular sort from the salesforce example.

```
var rowAColValue = new Date(rowAColValue);
var rowBColValue = new Date(rowBColValue);
```

This should work in AURA too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you SFDCfox! It's working for me, just instead of 'date' it should be 'Date' in the below snippet:

if(column.type==='date' || column.type==='datetime') {
parser = (v) => (v && new Date(v));
}

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for date sorting :

```
 sortDateData( direction) {       
        if (direction === 'asc') {
            this.data.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.dateFieldColumnName) - new Date(b.dateFieldColumnName));
        } else {
            this.emailLogs.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.dateFieldColumnName) - new Date(a.dateFieldColumnName));
        }
        this.data = [...this.data]; // To re-render the table with the sorted data

    }
```